# angularjs filter('filter') with exclude option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array of json objects like this:

```
$scope.data = [{ name: "something something", date: 982528 }, 
               { x: 1, y: { sub: 2}, prop1: "some string" }, 
               { a: "b", c: "d", e: "some string" }];
```

and I'm trying to filter it with:

```
var filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.data, "some string");
```

this way in all the properties of the objectes in the array, angular compares with the search string,

in this example it will return the las two objects,

now, what i need is to pass an array of properties like:

```
var exclude =  ['prop1'];
```

so the filter will omit to compare those properties in each object,
is there an angular filter with this option?

Comment: you can't exclude properties, but you can pass an object which defines which properties you are trying to include; i.e. `$filter('filter')($scope.data, {e: "some string"});` would only return objects where `e === "some string"`, but would not match this for other properties.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @Claies mmm the problem is those json objects are biiiiiiig, at least 50 properties each, and i only need to exclude like 4 at best...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you should create custom `excludeFilter`:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [
    { name: "something something", date: 982528 }, 
    { x: 1, y: { sub: 2}, prop1: "some string", prop2: "some string" }, 
    { a: "b", c: "d", e: "some string" }
  ];  
  $scope.search = 'some';
  $scope.exclude = ['prop1', 'prop2'];
}).filter('excludeFilter', function(){
  return function(data, search, exclude){
    if(!search)
      return data;
    return data.filter(function(x){
      for(var prop in x)
        if(exclude.indexOf(prop) == -1){           
           var value = x[prop];
           if(value.indexOf && value.indexOf(search) != -1)
              return true;
           if(!value.indexOf && value == search)
              return true;
        }          
      return false;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  search: <input type='text' ng-model='search'/>  
  <br>
  exclude: <input type='text' ng-model='exclude' ng-list/>    
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='x in data | excludeFilter : search : exclude'>{{x | json}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```